# Python Panda - concatenate two column values into a single column with label name

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a new column name as Result and value should be the name of label if the value is true.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Raja', 'Kumar', 'Muthu'], 'Car': [True, False, False], 'Bike': [True, True, False]})
```

**Expected Result**

```
    Name    Car   Bike  Result
0   Raja   True   True  Car-Bike
1  Kumar  False   True  Bike
2  Muthu  False  False  NaN
```

Comment: `df = df.set_index('Name'); df['Result'] = df.dot(df.columns+'-').str.strip('-')`

Comment: @cs95 It works, Thq